# Webpack output two css bundles for desktop and mobile

Tags: css, webpack

I have the following task:

given a source .css files I need to generate a name.main.css bundle with Webpack and I need to put a separate name.mobile.css bundle which is just name.main.css ran through PostCSS Hover plugin (I need to remove all :hover styles). The server would then decide which bundle to serve based on user agent...

Has anyone dealt with a similar task?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Please add the webpack config file of what you already have

Comment: Cannot do that unfortunately: NDA.

Comment: that is a job for a task runner, not for webpack.

Comment: And also if it was something you could do with webpack, we would need to know what you have done so far.